# A missing feature class in the list when adding classes to a new network dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network-dataset

I´m having a problem here when creating a new Network Dataset. Firstly I select the feature classes from the list that will participate in the network dataset. I have a feature dataset under a geodatabase file, which stores different road elements (major roads, private roads, biking and walking ways etc.) and lastly a feature class, where the information of all previously listed different road layers are in. That´s why this feature class layer is  important. I have made some modifications to this layer: I added fields in the attribute table that for example show the travel time by bicycling.

By some reason the New Network Dataset -wizard doesn´t find this feature class, that I´ve modified. Can you tell me why? Might it be the reason that I´ve changed it a bit and somehow that has also modified the way the feature dataset is being built? Do I have build it again somehow?

Comment: All the feature classes participating in the network need to be inside the dataset.